# defining props with TypeScript when using higher order component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have a component that needs to get injected from both parent (with PropA) and from HOC (with PropB)

```
export interface PropsA extends PropsB {
    propA: string;
}

class SomeComponent extends React.PureComponent<PropsA> {
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.propA}
                {this.props.propB}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withPropsB(SomeComponent);


export interface PropsB {
    propB: string;
}
```

This is how we inject it with HOC:

```
export const withPropsB = (Component: any) => {
    class EnhancedWithProsB extends React.Component<PropsB> {
        render(){
            return <Component {...this.props}/>;
        }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({
        propB: "propB"
    });

    return connect(mapStateToProps)(EnhancedWithProsB);
};
```

Client use it this way:

```
class Wrapper extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return <SomeComponent propA="propA" />;
    }
}
```

I got error saying that "Property 'propA' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes, ComponentState>> & ...'."

What type should withPropsB method return to make this error dissapear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to derive `EnhancedWithProsB` from `React.Component` with the same props as the component passed (in your case `PropsA`). A generic way to that would be:

```
export const withPropsB = <T extends PropsB>(Component: new(... p: any[])=>  React.PureComponent<T>) => {
    class EnhancedWithProsB extends React.Component<T> {
        render(){
            return <Component {...this.props}/>;
        }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({
        propB: "propB"
    });

    return connect(mapStateToProps)(EnhancedWithProsB);
};
```